# a combination formula proof used for Bayes estimation in hypergeometric distribution

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am doing a Bayes parameter estimation in a hypergeometric distribution，and it needs the following formula：
for any $x$ satisfying $0\leq x\leq n$
$$\sum_{m=0}^{N}{C_m^xC_{N-m}^{n-x}} = C_{N+1}^{n+1}$$
where
$$C_n^k = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$
$N,m,n$ are natural numbers and $n \leq N$.

I want to use $\sum_{m=0}^{N}{C_m^n} = C_{N+1}^{n+1}$ to prove this formula for it is the closest form that came in my mind, but I have no idea about the next step and whether it is the right direction.

Comment: Are you defining $C_n^k$ to mean $\frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes! Thank you for pointing out the problem! The question is updated now.